# string as function argument in R

Tags: r, string, function, arguments

Dataframe `chocolates` lists types of candy and a set of ratings for each:

```
ID          sweetness   filling   crash
snickers    0.67        0.55      0.40
milky_way   0.81        0.53      0.56
...
```

I'm writing a function that takes an argument for the filename, the ID for a particular type of candy, and the score I'm interested in (`sweetness`, `filling`, or `crash`) and returns a certain score for a certain candy in that file. For example, if I want the `sweetness` rating for the `ID` "snickers" (like the syntax below)...

```
> chocolates$sweetness[chocolates$ID=="snickers"]
[1] 0.67
```

...some function `candyranks(data=, ID=, score=)` should return the same value. Here's what I've written:

```
candyranks <- function(data, id, score){
  data$score[chocolates$ID=="snickers"]
}
```

But `candyranks(data=chocolates, ID = "snickers", score = sweetness)` returns a value of `NULL`. I've made sure `ID` is a character vector. Any ideas on why it wouldn't return a value of `0.67`?

Comment: Use `[[` instead of `$` inside function i.e. `data[[score]][chocolates$ID == "snickers"]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a working example:

First let's define a reproducible data frame:

```
chocolate <- data.frame(ID = c("snickers", "milky_way"),
                        sweetness = c(0.67, 0.81),
                        filling = c(0.55, 0.55),
                        crash = c(0.40, 0.56))
```

Now we want to make sure all of our arguments are not treated as column names, but rather object calls.  We also want to use our function arguments whenever appropriate to give the function a little more flexibility:

```
candyranks <- function(data, id, score){
  data[[score]][data$ID==id]
}
```

In this example, it's a little more flexible as it doesn't require a dataset to be called `chocolate`.  Giving us the following:

```
candyranks(data = chocolate, id = "snickers", score = "sweetness")
[1] 0.67
```

---

#### Alternative `dplyr` approach:

While base `R` is perfect for this case, I know some prefer `dplyr` syntax to see line-by-line what is happening.  The following *should* perform exactly as above for this dataset, but with `tidyverse` verbage:

```
candyranks <- function(data, id, score){
  require(dplyr)
  data %>% 
    filter(ID == id) %>% 
    pull(score)
}
```